# Magento Wordpress Integration auto login is not working

Tags: wordpress, magento, http-authentication, fishpig

I have used the Fishpig Magento Wordpress auto login plugin (version:3.0.20) and wordpress 3.8. 
If already wordpress is logged in, autologin works. otherwise it redirected to the following link and asks the credentials to enter.

http://www.domainname.com/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php&reauth=1

Answer (score 0):

Domain's SSL certificate is setup for a non-www URL but WordPress installed on a www. URL.

I have moved WordPress to a non-www URL and it is worked.